# How to enable retina mode on Mac OS X for Java apps

Tags: java, swing, retina-display

I want to draw in full [OSX Retina](http://www.apple.com/iphone/features/retina-display.html) resolution in Java Swing application during debugging from IDE. How can I do this? When I run an app from an IDE, it looks blurry.

Comment: i think he is basically just asking how to make *Retina* ready Java Applications

Comment: No, it's about debugging retina enabled app in full retina resolution from IDE. If you create an app bundle, you can use Info.plist to specify retina key but when you run from IDE, I don't know how to do the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed in jdk 7u40ea. Download from here https://jdk7.java.net/download.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue running Netbeans on a Retina MacBook Pro.
Key is that JDK 7 does not support Retina and you have to downgrade to JDK 6.

Description and solution here:
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=215141#c66

Comment: A fix has now been created for Java 8 and should be officially implemented soon: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/macosx-port-dev/2013-April/005491.html I'm not sure if there are plans to backport it to Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just about the IDE could you please let us know which IDE you are using.

For Eclipse 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382972

For IntelliJ IDEA
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87500

Comment: You misunderstood the question. It isn't about IDE it's about running application from IDE.