# Is There A Way To Disable Mac OS Retina Scaling For A Swing App?

Tags: java, macos, swing, retina-display, codenameone

We have a rather complex application that needs as much screen real-estate as it can get, naturally the retina display Mac Books are excellent for this purpose.

However, it seems that in Swing those devices use points rather than pixels. They allow me to change the icons to higher resolution versions as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017193/how-to-enable-retina-mode-on-mac-os-x-for-java-apps). But since we do a lot of complex graphics and components overlays I want to just use "real pixels". To be clear I am not interested in fixing blurry images or icons (not practical in my case) just to disable the pixel doubling.

There is [this](http://blog.beatunes.com/2013/04/creating-retina-capable-images-with.html) interesting (albeit hacky) option I found thru [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431148/swing-and-bitmaps-on-retina-displays).

Comment: similar question was asked one-two week(s) back, no idea about

Comment: Odd, I couldn't find that one? Do you have a link?

Comment: not I'm haven't, real reason I'm too lazy search for, only to remember (still empty 1_24Tb in my head, but without masking Q&A to URL)

Comment: Frustrating isn't it? Writing Swing code on Retina, we have a ton of pixels available but it's difficult to use them! Looking forward to a fix :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge this is not possible as of JDK 1.8. The only workaround is to detect retina and use the scale affine transform when drawing.
However, detecting retina seems to be a problem since the only option that seems to be available isn't on a per monitor case which is probably not a good solution:
[How can I detect whether a Mac has a Retina display from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716743/how-can-i-detect-whether-a-mac-has-a-retina-display-from-java)

Comment: There *is* a per-monitor detection method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53538597/1968